# Increasing and Decreasing Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I was asked on my weekly quiz to find give an example of a sequence that is increasing and decreasing at the same time.

Intuition tells me that we surely can't find a "regular" sequence that is increasing and decreasing at the same time. So I feel that they are playing with the definition here.

However, I am still not able to think of one. How definitions are being played here?

Will a sequence with the same number such as 1 only, qualify for this??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, $\{1,1,1...\}$ is  increasing  and decreasing.

Comment: Would this be the only answer? I mean the only type of sequence that is both decreasing and increasing can only be the one that contains the same number ? Like {2,2,2} or {3,3,3} etc.?

Comment: @YanZhuang Indeed, if you at any point have an element greater than its successor, the sequence is no longer increasing. Similarly for an element smaller than its successor and decreasing.

Comment: Sure thanks a lot! My brain was just clogged at that moment lol haha. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence $(x_n)$ is said to be increasing if $x_n \leq x_{n+1} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

A sequence $(x_n)$ is said to be decreasing if $x_n \geq x_{n+1} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Thus we have
$$x_n \leq x_{n+1} \text{ }\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
and
$$x_n \geq x_{n+1} \text{ }\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Now since $$x_n \leq x_{n+1}, \text{ }\text{ }x_n \geq x_{n+1} \Rightarrow  x_n = x_{n+1}$$

We conclude

$$x_n \leq x_{n+1}, \text{ }\text{ }x_n \geq x_{n+1} \text{ } \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow x_n = x_{n+1} \text{ } \text{ }\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Thus $c=x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5= \dots x_{n-1}=x_n=x_{n+1} \dots $

So your sequence if $(c,c,c,c,c,\dots c,c,c \dots )$

Note- You must be careful if someone asks you for a sequence which is "strictly increasing and decreasing" or "increasing and striclty decreasing"

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know why I never thought about this proof.